# mysql move the last N characters of each line of data to the next line

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I want move the last 3 characters of each line of data to the next line, the first line fill with xxx.

example:

[image]

now i have TableOne, i want get TableTwo, thanks!

[update]

mysql version is 5.7.22, not support lag function

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: What is your version of MySql/MariaDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your version of MySql/MariaDB supports window functions and you have already created TableTwo you can insert the new rows like this:

```
insert into TableTwo(id, num)
select
  id,
  concat(
    coalesce(lag(right(num, 3)) over (order by id), 'xxx'), 
    coalesce(left(num, 2), '')
  ) num
from (
  select * from TableOne
  union all
  select max(id) + 1, null from TableOne
) t;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=af709ce6adc422143081c287e02ac9ac).

Without window functions you can do it with a self join:

```
insert into TableTwo(id, num)
select
  t.id,
  concat(
    coalesce(right(t1.num, 3), 'xxx'), 
    coalesce(left(t.num, 2), '')
  ) num
from (
  select * from TableOne
  union all
  select max(id) + 1, null from TableOne
) t left join TableOne t1
on t1.id = t.id - 1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4920248e1be168a78f64b6d2bef5bf4d).

Results:

```
> id | num  
> -: | :----
>  1 | xxxab
>  2 | cde01
>  3 | 23456
>  4 | 789
```

Comment: thanks! but my mysql version is 5.7.22, not support lag function

Comment: @artwl see my 2nd query. It will work in case there are no gaps between the ids.